# What are the main differences between Firebase vs Firebase 2.0?

Tags: firebase

Google just released Firebase 2.0.

It seems they are completely separate platforms.

Firebase: https://www.firebase.com/

Firebase 2.0: https://firebase.google.com/

APIs are also different.

Firebase: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/

Firebase 2.0: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/#firebase

Could someone explain the differences in the core concepts on both mobile and web?

I've been building an app using old Firebase.

Should I change my codes to use Firebase 2.0?

Comment: Hi Joon. Firebaser here. Thanks for noticing the announcement. We're incredibly excited about finally releasing these big enhancements. As you can probably imagine we're a bit swamped for the moment, so I hope you can find the information you need on [our new documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) and [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/05/firebase-expands-to-become-unified-app-platform.html). I'll check back soon to follow-up and see if you have more questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new version of Firebase is the same platform - it just adds a whole range of new features, so the big change to the core concepts is an expansion of what you can do.

The [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) offers the same functionality as before, but with a refreshed API and a new console. You can keep using the same approach and data model as before, and the API changes are largely cosmetic (renaming to be consistent with the newer features).

[Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) is pretty similar, but it has been expanded to include new features like account linking and customizable emails. You should be able to upgrade your application to the new SDKs and console pretty easily: take a look at our migration guides for [Android](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android), [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios) and the [web](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web).

You can import your project at any time. Your applications and the **existing SDKs will continue to work**. You can then update your code when you are ready to use some of the new Firebase features in your application.

The new concepts are really around the new features:

- [Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) is a new mobile-first analytics product that gives free and unlimited event reporting, and allows building audiences which can be used in many other services.
- [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) allows you to store and serve user-generated content, such as photos or videos.
- [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) allows you to change the behavior and appearance of your app without publishing an app update.
- [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably deliver messages and notifications at no cost. [Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) gives you a tool in the Firebase Console to send re-engagement messages easily.
- [Crash Reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/) lets you collect crash data from your Android and iOS apps, to find and fix problems more quickly.
- [Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) are smart URLs that dynamically change behavior to provide the best experience across different platforms. They allow you to use deep links that survive app installs on Android and iOS.

Several existing Google products have been integrated into Firebase as well
[Invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/) replaced AppInvites, giving easy way to sending personalized email and SMS invitations. [App Indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/) gets your app into Google search.

Firebase now also [integrates with AdWords](https://firebase.google.com/docs/adwords/) to let you target ad campaigns with Analytics audiences, and [AdMob](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/) to automatically track in-app ad effectiveness.

Its a lot of new features, but you don't have to try them all at once! Once you upgrade, its straightforward to pick and choose.

Comment: You can now also run node.js backend code via Firebase Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/